# What will happen if I take an item costing 3 soul hearts but I don't have enough?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

I'm currently the the Devil room and am being offered a Sister Maggie for 3 soul hearts.

The predicament is that I only have 1 soul heart.

What will happen if I try to take Sister Maggie?

Comment: The [Isaac Wikia](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Devil_Room) states that you can buy a 1 heart item with 3 soul hearts, so it may be that you will cash in one of your hearts for 3 soul hearts, and be left with 1 soul heart.  The game doesn't always make sense though, so I'm not posting this as an answer. :)  Also, if that one soul heart is the only life you have left, you will die.

Comment: @agent86 I'm debating just doing it since I have 10 hearts and a soul heart, and then I can post the answer myself, but I'm not really interested in having a Sister Maggie (I'd rather even one heart than it) unless it'll only take away my one soul heart.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's physically impossible for you to take an item costing more soul hearts than you currently have.

If you attempt to, you will just move through the item as if it doesn't exist.

Comment: I can confirm that, it's the same like trying to buy something you cannot afford in the shop

Comment: +1 for confirmation. I tried buying a 3 soul heart Pentagram when I only had 2 soul hearts. Just passed right through it, and left. Hanging my head in shame...

Comment: @Tristan That's actually kind of the game. I'd expect it to take the hearts and give you nothing (which is still better than death, which is what happens with regular hearts).

Comment: I can't say I'm surprised, but it seems like a bug.